# Where can I find Android Vanilla/stock apps source code?

Tags: android

Android comes in many flavors, but all of them include some built in apps. Some manufacturers also add their own apps.

I know this sounds like a general question, but which of the apps that you know of (of Google, Samsung, LG,...) are open source and can be learned/tinkered with?

More importantly, how can you get them?

As an example of apps that could be nice to know of their source code:

1. Google's/Samsung's contacts app.
2. Google's dialer/phone app.
3. Google's camera app.
4. Samsung's multi window feature.
5. Samsung's locker (keyguard).
6. Google's gallery app.
7. Google's launcher app.

and there are many more...

Maybe we could even offer our improvement in the code for helping the companies make their apps better.

Comment: Check out the AOSP and code.google.com for the open sourced Google apps.  The OEM apps are all closed, those are a large part of the extra value they think they provide Android.  Many Google apps are not open source either, many require the OEM to follow a large set of rules to use (for example Play and Maps), they're the carrot to give Google leverage to force OEM behavior.

Comment: Also, Google is pretty infamous for not being too willing to take community changes into Android for some reason.

Comment: @GabeSechan I didn't ask which are closed source. I asked which ones you know that are open source and where I can find them and get them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a opengrok so you can view code online, and here is source code of google contacts:
http://androidxref.com/4.2_r1/xref/packages/apps/Contacts/

there is google camera:

http://androidxref.com/4.2_r1/xref/packages/apps/Camera/

Google gallery:

http://androidxref.com/4.2_r1/xref/packages/apps/Gallery/

Dialer is included in Contacts and phone:

http://androidxref.com/4.2_r1/xref/packages/apps/Phone/

Comment: This is very nice. Do you know of other apps ? like the launcher for example?

Comment: http://androidxref.com/4.2_r1/xref/packages/apps/Launcher2/ launcher.  you can find almost apps in packages/apps

Comment: So cool! Thank you so much. Do you know of other manufacturers open source apps ?

Comment: Other manufactures's apps may not be open source. As I know, Samsung just provides the kernel source code not app's. Anyway, you can check it in http://opensource.samsung.com/index.jsp to find out whether they provides the source code of apps.

Comment: What about other manufacturers besides Samsung? Some of them have some really cool things too...

Comment: Here is htc dev center: http://www.htcdev.com/resources/android-links . But don't expect too much, most of them are not open source.

Comment: I don't think they have anything. Too bad. I know it could be against their interests (other companies might copy it), but people could help them make better code too.

Comment: Hi. How to download it?